# How can I only allow the user to complete a reCAPTCHA using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver (in Java) to get some info from a site after logging in. This requires the user to complete a reCAPTCHA test. Everything before and after this is done automatically and the user does not need to see or do anything.

I would normally use a headless browser, but I need the GUI so that the user can manually complete the reCAPTCHA. Currently I am using `ChromeDriver` and `WebDriverWait` to wait until it is complete and then continue with my stuff. I am fine with this-- the user completes the test while everything else is automated. However, if the user does anything besides the test (new tabs, entering stuff in address bar), things get messed up. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to bypass someone's TOS; we cannot help you with that here. Contact the website owner and ask them if they have an API.

Comment: @SiKing I'm not trying to get a bot to pose as human; there will be a human user manually completing the test. The reCAPTCHA is there to prevent spam or automatic attempts to guess a password, neither of which my program can do since a human has to pass the every time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Captcha is intended to defeat automated programs like Selenium, and getting around CAPTCHAs is difficult by design. It does after all stand for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart". Typically, one has to configure the website in certain ways in order to disable the CAPTCHA for testing purposes. Though this will help automate the test in a smoother way, it compromises the security of the application. If your dev team allows this, then ask them to disable it for the purpose of running automated tests.

You will have to enter the CAPTCHA yourself while other fields will be filled automatically. This method only achieves automation to a certain point. Basically, the only way is using the WAIT command to tell the script to wait and complete the CAPTCHA manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I don't intend to bypass the CAPTCHA automatically. I want a human user to complete it manually, like you said. My current method with `WebDriverWait` works decently -- fields are filled out automatically, the user completes the CAPTCHA, and the automation continues after completion. This is what I want. But if the user does pretty much anything (create new tab, navigate away, etc), it screws things up really bad. That's the main thing I want to prevent.

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is set up a wait to see if the captcha field is no longer visible. Or if the target window is closed.